# Getting '-2147221005': 'Invalid class string' error while trying to create objects using 'sp_OACreate'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run the below script that creates `EASendMailObj.Mail` object using `sp_OACreate`, but getting:

> '-2147221005': 'Invalid class string' error.

What could be the issue?

```
DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @oSmtp int
DECLARE @result int
DECLARE @description nvarchar(255)

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'EASendMailObj.Mail',@oSmtp OUT
print @hr

If @hr <> 0
BEGIN
     EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetErrorInfo @oSmtp, NULL, @description OUT

     IF @hr = 0
     BEGIN
         PRINT @description
     END

     RETURN 
End
```